# Create std-compliant allocator that wraps arbitrary allocator for diagnostics

Tags: c++, templates, allocator

As part of a unit test suite for custom std-compatible containers, I want to do some memory tracking. The easiest thing is to define a new allocator and track allocations and deallocations with it, and call malloc and free. However, there are cases when I want to use a different allocator as a *sub allocator* and route all allocations through it. This is kind of working except for the rebind required by containers. It is also limited to the std::allocator, which is not great for unit testing with other allocators. I am using C++/17 to do this.

So far I have this working example allocator, but the type of the base allocator is fixed - it only works with std::allocators.

```
template <typename T, typename BaseAllocator = std::allocator<T> >
struct TrackingAllocator
{
    typedef T value_type;

    TrackingAllocator() = default;
    TrackingAllocator( const TrackingAllocator& aOther ) noexcept = default;

    template <class U>
    constexpr TrackingAllocator( const TrackingAllocator<U, std::allocator<U>>& ) noexcept {}

    // recognize this is old style; would like to move to new style C++17 rebind
    template <class U>
    struct rebind
    {
        using other = TrackingAllocator<U, std::allocator<U>>;
    };

    BaseAllocator m_allocator;

    T* allocate( std::size_t n )
    {
        // track allocation
        return m_allocator.allocate( n );
    }

    void deallocate( T* p, std::size_t n ) noexcept
    {
        // track deallocation
        m_allocator.deallocate( p, n );
    }
    // allocation logging
};
```

However, I need it to work with any kind of allocator:

`std::vector<int, TrackingAllocator< FixedAllocator<int> > > vector_of_ints;`

My goal is to be able to write tests such as:

```
TrackingAllocator<int> trackingAllocator;
{
    CustomContainer<TrackingAllocator<int>> container ( trackingAllocator );

    // a bunch of allocation-related operations
    EXPECT_EQ( trackingAllocator.allocationCount, the_expected_number );

    container.shrink_to_fit();

    EXPECT_EQ( trackingAllocator.allocationCount, the_expected_number );
}
// container out of scope, free memory in container
EXPECT_EQ( trackingAllocator.allocationCount, 0 );
```

But I am struggling with two issues:

1. How to get modern rebind working as rebind has been deprecated in C++17
2. Rebind the *sub allocator* to the new type U as well.

The issue I am getting is that I cannot return the correct T* from the rebound allocator in this call:

```
    T* allocate( std::size_t n )
    {
        // m_allocator's T and the rebound Tracking
        // allocator's T are not related.
        return m_allocator.allocate( n );
    }
```

Any way I can solve this?

Comment: Have you seen [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits)? Presumably it should be enough to make your allocator play nice with it.

Comment: And if I gather correctly, you basically just need `m_allocator` to always be the rebound version of `BaseAllocator` to `T`, which will make your `TrackingAllocator` template work with `rebind_alloc`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes - I will update my question with the error I am getting; but also it needs to be able to take an arbitrary type of sub-allocator at the original declaration.

Comment: The arbitrary sub-allocator should be a valid allocator itself (otherwise, how can you fulfill all allocator requirements?), so rebinding it with `std::allocator_traits` is something I think you can rely on, regardless of it being standard or not.

Comment: Rebind like this: `using other = std::allocator_traits<BaseAllocator>::rebind_alloc<U>;`  you may also need to provide constructors for the general case; make sure to default the copy+move constructor+assignment too. I would eventually publicly inherit rather than compose the allocator, because now you need to define four constexpr values as equal to their`allocator_traits<BaseAllocator>::` counterparts.